# Assign a constructor to an std::function variable

Tags: c++

I would like to assign a specific constructor of the `string` class (the one that takes `char*`) to an std::function variable, like so:

```
std::function<string(char*)> stringConstructor = std::string; // incorrect
```

More generally, I would like to be able to pass this constructor as a parameter to another function that takes an argument of type `std::function<string(char*)>`. Is this possible?

Comment: The other question is somewhat more specialized (it wants the constructor of a type specified with a template), but the answer is applicable to yours.

Comment: Like the answer to the other question says - `std::string` is the name of the class, not the name of a constructor. The constructor doesn't *have* a name on its own.